# Where does Python modules installed on Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I understand the azure machine learning studio (classic) version using Anaconda distribution but my question is where would the python modules like pandas/tensorflow are installed when using **IPython interface of Azure ML**. Is this on AML studio itself or in azure blob (AML studio uses blob as backend store)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my screenshots for tabs `EXPERIMENTS` and `NOTEBOOKS` in Azure Machine Learning Studio (classic), as the figures below.

Fig 1. I created a `Excute Python Script` module with the code to print the `sys.path` and the real path of `pandas` installed.

[image]

Fig 2. The `View output log` page of the code in Fig 1 shows `EXPERIMENTS` is a runtime of Anaconda on Windows.

[image]

Fig 3. I created a notebook named `demo` and run the same code as Fig 1, the result shows `NOTEBOOKS` is a runtime of Anaconda on Linux, even the notenooks url is started with `notebooks.azure.com`.

[image]

Fig 4. I used different commands like `lsb_release -a`, `fdisk -l`, `lsdev`, `ls /dev`, `df -a` to try to see the Linux version and its disk or partition information, the result shows it's a Ubuntu Linux container.

[image]

Other infomation what you want to know, you can try to check by yourself.

Comment: Big thanks for your inputs, this is super helpful. One last question, in Fig 2 - when you say experiments is runtime of conda on "Windows". This windows is not the user's windows machine right? Thanks again

Comment: @Idleguys Yeah, it seems to be a virtual environment with Anaconda Python running on Windows VM as a service like Azure WebApp, I think.

Comment: Thanks again, it makes sense @PeterPan